# Ubuntu terminal startup instead of desktop

Tags: software-center, wubi

Good day

I am VERY much an amateur when it comes to software and coding in general. However, I am willing to learn.

I am in desperate need of running TITAN Radar software on my system. This program should only be run on a LINUX system, which I have attempted.

In my experience of trying to install Ubuntu, I have failed countless times. I use a Windows system so it is preferable that I keep it this way. Therefore, I have attempted using wubi.

wubi installs successfully. When I start my system, I choose the "Ubuntu" option. Thereafter, I select to run the generic version of the software. A terminal looking screen the opens up and requests my username and password. However, this is not what I am looking for, as I don't understand the coding language. What I am essentially asking is the following: How do I get the software to open up with a desktop asking for my login details, instead of a terminal asking for my username and password.

In addition, once I have successfully moved on to solve the Ubuntu problem described above, is there anyway you can assist me in installing TITAN Radar software? The link to install this is http://www.ral.ucar.edu/projects/titan/docs/TitanInstall.pdf . I need basic LROSE software. If you could assist in any way possible, it would contribute a GREAT amount to the research I am conducting.

Regards,
A very desperate Master's student,
Todd

Comment: Given the hardware requirements of TITAN Radar software in the pdf that you linked, I would recommend you to try one more time to install Ubuntu in your hard drive. My personal choice would be Kubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 16.04. You can first try to install it using Virtualbox if you want to practice. Then follow one of the installation guides, after you backup all your data, just in case ;)

Comment: Wubi is not active project and doesn't work on recent versions. Given the requirements of the hardware (and especially discrete graphics), if you can afford it, you might consider a System76 computer where installation and graphics drivers are taken care of. If you already have 16GB ram, you could run linux in VMware Player or VirtualBox. If you currently only have 8, you'll need to dual boot. Please search the site for questions on that. :)

Comment: also, after removing wubi, you'll need to repair the windows boot (unless you install ubuntu before or immediately after removing wubi). There's other questions on the site about that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input and contribution. I have decided to scratch wubi completely and use VirtualBox. Turnsout, my virtualization setting in BIOS was disabled. I am now able to work on ubuntu 16.04 from my desktop (windows). Now i just have to figure out how to install TITAN Radar software.